# Set difference of an open and a bounded set is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

An exercise in a course material i'm following doesn't seem right, it asks to show the following:

Let $X$ be a metric space and $G\subset X$ open. If $F\subset G$ is bounded, then $G\setminus F$ is open.

If we place no extra restrictions on the set $F$, then we can for example choose $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric, $G=B(0,1)$ and $F=B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}$. Then $G\setminus F=\{0\}$, which certainly is not open and thus presents a counterexample? Am i very confused or is the exercise flawed?

Comment: The exercise is flawed and your counterexample works fine to show that. (By $0$, I assume you mean the origin.)

Comment: $F$ should be closed for this to hold.

Comment: Ok great thanks, these things always make you worried you've understood something terribly wrong. Yeah i meant the origin.